# Why Selenium Google Colab is giving empty csv data?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-colaboratory

1. I run this below script on google colab, it is working without problem and also gives output as csv which i want, but it is empty csv. why does this happen and how i can get csv data correctly in which there must be information scraped from the target website?

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJwYE.png)

Note: At the time of getting screenhot, there was data on the target website, it was not empty.

2. Besides, when i run this code on google colab, it is not opening test chrome browser, normally after running this code there must appear test chrome browser. Why i do not see it?

```
!apt-get update

!apt install chromium-chromedriver

!cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin

!pip install selenium

from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

options.add_argument('--headless')

options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')

options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')


wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=options)

wd.get('http://arsiv.mackolik.com/Genis-Iddaa-Programi')

import pandas as pd

import time

timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")

first_team= wd.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="resultsList"]/tbody/tr/td[6]/a')

second_team= wd.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="resultsList"]/tbody/tr/td[7]/a')


my_list1=[]

my_list2=[]


for name in first_team:

    print(name.text)
    my_list1.append(name.text)

for name in second_team:

    print(name.text)
    my_list2.append(name.text)


df = pd.DataFrame({ 

    'FIRST TEAM': my_list1, 
    'SECOND TEAM': my_list2
})

df.to_csv(f'{timestr}.csv')

wd.quit()
```

Comment: you did use "--headless" as an arg there... which means if Chrome is launching you won't see it.  Check to see if your arrays are empty or if the dataset is empty.   That would narrow it down to the panda bits...

Comment: dataset which i save it is empty, in the csv i have no information.

Comment: is the dataset/frame empty before calling to_csv?

Comment: Please share a self-contained notebook that reproduces the problem. (The screenshot is not sufficiently complete to reproduce the issue.)

Comment: the code running on google colab is as like this.

Comment: any comment on this one?